# Mongodb update number field with arithmetic operator

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a number field named "reference". I want to update every document in the collection and add 1000 to the reference field.

so if reference = 1 it will become 1001

pseudo below:

```
db.item.updateMany({}, {$set:{reference: reference+1000}}
```

Any idea how best to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$inc` operator

```
db.item.updateMany({}, { $inc: { reference: 10000 }});
```